# Regular expression to split string and number

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a string of the form:

```
codename123
```

Is there a regular expression that can be used with [`Regex.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularxpressions.regex.split.aspx) to split the alphabetic part and the numeric part into a two-element string array?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I know you asked for the `Split` method, but as an alternative you could use named capturing groups:

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
var match = numAlpha.Match("codename123");

var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
var num = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;
```

Comment: +1 I remember ever seeing one of such implementations for parsing INI files and I honestly thought it's very wonderful.

Comment: Using named capturing groups sure beats doing `array[0]`, but that is just me :)

Comment: If the alphabetic part and the numeric part are both *required* to be present, the regex expression is incorrect. It should be `(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)`

Comment: Would this work for a string like this?
"1/0ACSR" so it comes out with "1/0" and "ACSR" ?

Comment: Answered my own question:
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Numeric>[0-9]*/*[0-9]*)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)");

Comment: I completely copy pasted your code. but `alpha` stays `NULL` when I match the regex with "69DD", while `num` gets filled with 69.

could somebody explain to me why this happens?

Comment: @FllnAngl - This expression is order dependent. `Alpha` comes before `Numeric`

Answer (score 10):

```
splitArray = Regex.Split("codename123", @"(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{N})");
```

will split between a Unicode letter and a Unicode digit.

Answer (score 5):

Regex is a little heavy handed for this, if your string is always of that form. You could use

```
"codename123".IndexOfAny(new char[] {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'})
```

and two calls to Substring.

Comment: Yup your way is much faster

Answer (score 5):

IMO, it would be a lot easier to find matches, like:

```
Regex.Matches("codename123", @"[a-zA-Z]+|\d+")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(m => m.Value)
     .ToArray();
```

rather than to use `Regex.Split`.

Answer (score 4):

A little verbose, but

```
Regex.Split( "codename123", @"(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)" );
```

Can you be more specific about your requirements?  Maybe a few other input examples.

Comment: There might be backslashes in the codename, but other than that, if it works with "code\name123", it should work for my purposes.

Comment: This will split the string into `codename`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Comment: @Tim, corrected, thanks.  I forget that \w matches alphanumeric, not just alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Well, is a one-line only: `Regex.Split("codename123", "^([a-z]+)");`

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way is

```
string originalstring = "codename123";
string alphabets = string.empty;
string numbers = string.empty;

foreach (char item in mainstring)
{
   if (Char.IsLetter(item))
   alphabets += item;
   if (Char.IsNumber(item))
   numbers += item;
}
```

Comment: Probably an old question but that is what the regular expression do under the hood, although in an efficient and optimized way

Answer (score 0):

this code is written in java/logic should be same elsewhere

```
public String splitStringAndNumber(String string) {
    String pattern = "(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    if (m.find()) {
        return (m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
    }
    return "";
}
```